# Bootstrap cssStyle tag ignored Spring MVC 3.2.8

Tags: html, css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I have this input text in my JSP, using a Bootstrap class

```
<input type="text" name="device" class="form-control" id="device" placeholder="IOS/Android" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='IOS/Android'" onfocus="if(this.value=='IOS/Android') this.value='';" onkeypress="" />
```

But using the spring tag the style is totally ignored !

```
<form:input path="device" placeholder="IOS/Android" cssStyle="form-control" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='IOS/Android'" onfocus="if(this.value=='IOS/Android') this.value='';" onkeypress=""  />
```

Comment: should it be `cssClass` instead of `cssStyle`?

Comment: true, convert to answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to use `cssClass` instead of `cssStyle`.